# How to retrieve recursive path to a specific key (not displaying the parents' key name, but the value from a different key of each parent)

Tags: json, recursion, jq

I have the following JSON

```
[
  {
    "name": "alpha"
  },
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "beta_sub_1"
      },
      {
        "name": "beta_sub_2"
      }
    ],
    "name": "beta"
  },
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "gamma_sub_sub_1"
          }
        ],
        "name": "gamma_sub_1"
      }
    ],
    "name": "gamma"
  }
]
```

and I would like to get the paths of "name" needed to get to each "name" values. Considering the above code, I would like the following result:

```
"alpha"
"beta.beta_sub_1"
"beta.beta_sub_2"
"beta"
"gamma.gamma_sub_1.gamma_sub_sub_1"
"gamma.gamma_sub_1"
"gamma"
```

I've been searching around but I couldn't get to this result. So far, I have this:

```
tostream as [$p,$v]   | select($p[-1] == "name" and $v != null)   | "\([$p[0,1]] | join(".")).\($v)"
```

but this gives me the path with the key name of the parents (and doesn't keep all the intermediary parents.

```
"0.name.alpha"
"1.fields.beta_sub_1"
"1.fields.beta_sub_2"
"1.name.beta"
"2.fields.gamma_sub_sub_1"
"2.fields.gamma_sub_1"
"2.name.gamma"
```

Any ideas?

P.S.: I've been searching for very detailed doc on jq but couldn't find anything good enough. If anyone has any recommendations, I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem description does not seem to match the sample input and output, but the following jq program produces the required output:

```
def descend:
  select( type == "object" and has("name") )
  | if has("fields") then ([.name] + (.fields[] | descend)) else empty end, 
    [.name] ;

.[]
| descend
| join(".")
```

With your input, and using the -r command-line option, this produces:

```
alpha
beta.beta_sub_1
beta.beta_sub_2
beta
gamma.gamma_sub_1.gamma_sub_sub_1
gamma.gamma_sub_1
gamma
```

### Resources

Apart from the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), [FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ), and [Cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook), you might find the following helpful:

- ["jq Language Description"](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/jq-Language-Description)
- ["A Stream-Oriented Introduction to jq"](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works like a charm! For the description, I wasn't sure how to explain my problem clearly without writing a paragraph :/

And thanks as well for the links!